# Why doesn't *(ptr++) give the next item in the array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
int my_array[] = {1,23,17,4,-5,100};
int *ptr;
int i;
ptr = &my_array[0];     /* point our pointer to the first
                         element of the array */
printf("\n\nptr = %d\n\n", *ptr);
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    printf("my_array[%d] = %d   ",i,my_array[i]);   /*<-- A */
    printf("my_array[%d] = %d\n",i, *(ptr++));        /*<-- B */
}
```

Why does this display the same thing for both line a and b?  It just displays all of the values in my_array in order (1, 23, 17, 4, -5, 100).  Why does the '++' in line B not  point ptr to the next element of the array before it is dereferenced?  Even if you change that line to

```
printf("ptr + %d = %d\n",i, *ptr++);        /*<-- B */
```

the output is the same.  Why is this?

Comment: This is why having side effects in statements is often considered poor code.  Putting `ptr++` on its own line before the `printf()` would give the correct result, and reduce the chance of glancing eyes missing an important statement.

Comment: What had the C++ tag in common with this question?

Answer (score 14):

ptr++ increments ptr but returns the original value
++ptr increments and returns the new value

Hence the joke about c++ - it's one more than c but you use the original value = c

Comment: So variable++ is not always equivalent to variable + 1 then eh?

Comment: variable++ is equal to original=variable;variable=variable+1;return original

Comment: Personally I think C++ is best described as `(C90 ^ ++C90) | --C99`.

Comment: @Lundin, I was trying to put it in simple terms

Comment: @Martin No, no! Apart from the meaning of the statement itself, the needlessly complex, obfuscated code is much more suitable to describe C++!    :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are puzzled by the fact that the parenthesis do not change the value returned as you expectd.

Maybe it would be clearer to you if you think it in English:

p++ means *take the value of p, increment the value of p, return the initial value of p*

so, `*p++` would dereference the original value of `p`.

Considering that the value of `(x)` is the same as `x`, the value of `(p++)` is the same as `p++`.

Hence, `*(p++)` will dereference `p`, exactly as `*p++` does.

Answer (score 1):

In C there is a difference between post incrementing p++ and preincrementing ++p

p++ : uses the current value of p and then updates it
++P: updates the value of p and then uses it

hence your code should use ++ptr

Comment: Huh? In C there is a difference between post incrementing p++ and preincrementing --p?

Comment: --p would be pre-decrementing. (http://cplus.about.com/od/glossar1/g/predecdefn.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It is evident from the naming post-increment and pre-increment. Meaning, the variable is incremented post the operation or before the operation.

A post-increment operator creates a temporary variable to store the current value and increments the variable (but returns the temporary variable with current value). In pre-increment operator, there is no temporary variable. The same variable is incremented and returned.

So using post-increment operator in the same statement, means using the current value of the variable and incrementing after this statement. Whereas post-increment operator means incrementing the variable and using it in the current statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 types of operators : Postfix and Prefix .
*ptr++ is postfix operator means first use and then increase
while ++ptr means prefix operator means first increase and then use.

if you add another printf with printing the value of just *ptr in  your existing code you will notice the difference how the things go about.

Comment: Why does *(ptr++) print the same thing as *ptr++ then?  Shouldn't the first statement move ptr to the next value in the array before dereferencing?

Comment: That is the point I have trying to make ... *(ptr++) will move ptr to the next place the next time you use ptr as this is POST fix operator first use then increment on the other hand *(++ptr) will first move ptr ahead and then dereference it to give you the value, this operator being PRE fix!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this whole issue, write either of these alternatives:

```
++ptr;
printf("my_array[%d] = %d\n",i, *ptr);
```

or

```
printf("my_array[%d] = %d\n",i, *ptr);
++ptr;
```

This will yield the *same* number of instructions, but with the following major advantages:

- Is now more readable and understandable.
- If ptr would be used several times in the printf() statement, you need not worry about the order of evaluation of function parameters or operands, which are unspecified in the C language (with a few rare exceptions). Had you writted `printf("%d %d", *++ptr, *++ptr);` you can't know the result, as the code would then rely on order of evaluation, i.e. it contains a possibly severe bug.